# Django Rest Framework for Calculations

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

I'm starting to develop in django/django rest framework and I needed to make a kind of calculator, send a and b, python would take these values, process, for example, do the sum and return in a json, but I only find examples with database data, would it be possible to do this?

Comment: Yeah, look into https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/ APIView would be good for your purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Function-Based Views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#function-based-views)

You can pass the values of a and b using URL param into view, and could return the response after calculations.

Example:

```
# views.py
# imports 
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

# function-based view
@api_view(['POST'])
def calculate(request, a, b):
    result = a + b 
    return Response({"message": f"{result}"})
```

urls.py would look like this;

```
# imports
from django.urls import path
from . import views as views # if urls.py and views.py are in same dir

urlpatterns = [
     path('calculate/<int:a>/<int:b>/',
         views.calculate, name="calculate"),
]
```

It's not mandatory to use function-based views. but that made it easier to achieve functionally what you wanted.

Answer (score -2):

##### Views.py

```py
#importing the required libraries

from rest_framework import APIView

from rest_framework.response import Response

class calculateView(APIView):

     if request.method == 'POST':
        def calc(request,a,b):
            result = a+b
            return Response(result)
```

##### URL of the listing page

```py
from django.urls import path

from . import views

pattern_urls = [
    path('calculate/<int:a>/<int:b>/', views.calculateView.as_view(), name='calculate'),   
]
```